# What or Who are user{number}?

Tags: support, users

Every once in a while, I'll find a username in the format of user{number}, where {number} is an integer.

What do these users mean? Are they guests, or still to-be-approved accounts?

Comment: You had a name like that before you changed it :P

Comment: @MatthewRead I think a username was required back then, when there was only SO, and OpenID wasn't an option yet.

Comment: Do accounts get approved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A default username is generated for anyone who posts (registered or unregistered) of the form `user<number>`, where the number is simply an auto-incremented integer. Anyone who chooses not to create some kind of username for themselves (which is optional) will be assigned one of these automatically.